# Returning const in a function does not make the variable to be const?

Tags: c++, constants

I have the following structure:

```
class Test {
public:
    int k = 10;
};

class SecondTest {
private:
    Test t;
public:
    const Test& myTest() {
        return t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SecondTest secondTest;
    Test tt = secondTest.myTest();
    tt.k = 20;
    cout << "tt.k value: " << tt.k;
}
```

I thought that:

```
const Test& myTest() {
```

would make the returning value to be const.

But no I can simply assign to a non const value and use is as a non const stuff:

```
Test tt = secondTest.myTest();
```

The print result will be

```
"tt.k value: 20"
```

This sounds so strange for me... am I missing some concept on this?

Comment: tt is a  copy, not the original

Comment: Ow ok, this is the concept I was missing, in other languages the return would be a reference but here is by value.

Comment: Type `Test& tt = secondTest.myTest();` and you will see the difference

Comment: the thing returned from the function IS a reference. the thing referred to is then used to copy construct tt

Comment: `Test tt = secondTest.myTest();` makes a **copy** of the returned const reference.  And you have not made the copy const.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Test tt = secondTest.myTest()
```

The function returns a reference to a const object. That object can't be modified.

But the `Test tt = ...` part triggers the copy constructor that makes a copy. This copy can be modified.

Had you written

```
Test& tt = secondTest.myTest()
```

the compiler would have emitted an error preventing you from getting a non-const reference to this object. And if you kept a `const Test&`, then you wouldn't have been able to modify it.